# How to hook C++ functions with asm

Tags: c++, assembly, hook, reverse-engineering

I want to hook a C++ function. But I don't want to use the trampoline mechanism of ms detours, instead of it I want to fully patch it. I can get the handle to the DLL, where the function is located and I have the right offset(imageBase stuff ...). So how to hook it? And I don't know the data types of the arguments(var_4 and arg_0), or aren't they needed? In general I want to replace following function with my own one(my function is nearly the same, there's only a line changed):

```
sub_39001A40    proc near

    var_4       = dword ptr -4
    arg_0       = dword ptr  4
        push    ecx
        cmp dword_392ADAB4, 0
        jnz short loc_39001A4F
        call    loc_39024840

loc_39001A4F:
        push    esi
        mov esi, [esp+8+arg_0]
        lea eax, [esp+8+var_4]
        push    eax
        push    esi
        call    dword_392ADA98
        mov ecx, [esp+10h+var_4]
        add esp, 8
        add dword_392ADA80, ecx
        adc dword_392ADA84, 0
        add dword_392ADA90, esi
        pop esi
        adc dword_392ADA94, 0
        add dword_392ADA7C, 1
        pop ecx
        retn
sub_39001A40    endp
```

It's bad, that I only can hook functions, which names I know with ms detours. I cannot hook those asm functions with detours, cause I need the data types of the arguments passed for creating the function structures!

EDIT::::

"What's wrong with detours, exactly?"

I wrote: "I don't want to use the trampoline mechanism of ms detours, instead of it I want to fully patch it." and "It's bad, that I only can hook functions, which names I know with ms detours. I cannot hook those asm functions with detours, cause I need the data types of the arguments passed for creating the function structures!" and I don't have the source code of the C++ files. I only have the hex-dump.

"Trampoline is an actual technical term :) I'm just wondering why @lua can't use it."

I write: Read my sentences again, if you still don't understand why, my english is bad.

"Overriding just the named function should work, of course you may need to re-implement the whole DLL (depending on if it is of any further use to you). Given your grasp of assembler you might get away with using a hex editor to edit (a copy of) the original DLL you are seeking to subvert."

I want to hook the function, because I don't want to edit the file. I can't overwrite my function, because I don't know the datatypes of the arguments and the function's name.

@asveikau: Thanks for your real help, but I don't want to use a trampoline mechanism, I want to overwrite the function.

Comment: What's wrong with detours, exactly?

Comment: @bdonlan, I've obviously underestimated lua here. I though trampoline was used as a denigratory term for the bloat of ms mechanisms. Seems detours is actually a well known program I know nothing about.

Comment: Trampoline is an actual technical term :) I'm just wondering why @lua can't use it.

Comment: @lua: What exactly do you want to change in the function (note that different assembly lines compile into instructions of different length, so depending on what you want to change it might be really easy or really hard)?

Comment: a decent example in the question here, i guess http://stackoverflow.com/q/29093398/1067003

Answer (score 1):

A good trick is to replace the first few instructions with this:

```
push dword xxxx ; where xxx = new code location
ret
```

This is sort of like an obfuscated `jmp`.  I write it this way because the assembled version of this is very easy to replace the `push` operand with your pointer at runtime.  It assembles to:

```
68 XX XX XX XX c3
```

Where "XX XX XX XX" is your address in little-endian.

Then you can make a "call the old version of the function" code location, where the first few instructions are the ones you replaced with the sequence above, followed by a jump to the next valid instruction in the original code.

Comment: The hard part, of course, is correctly relocating the original instructions, when it's possible that the function may jump back into its own start, etc...

Comment: Also note that this is basically the same approach as detours uses.

Comment: @bdonlan - Yes, this is most likely what detours does, and yes, it does have limitations if the first 6 bytes of the instruction gets referenced again, either by a jump or through other means.  If I had to guess I'd say the latter is infrequent with C code though, since most functions will start with boring stuff like setting up frame pointers.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding just the named function should work, of course you may need to re-implement the whole DLL (depending on if it is of any further use to you). Given your grasp of assembler you might get away with using a hex editor to edit (a copy of) the original DLL you are seeking to subvert.