# Win32, How can i hook functions in compiled programs with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, assembly, hook

Take for instance this function (viewed in Ollydbg debugger) [image]

The first PUSH EBP instruction is the start for a void* f(int32_t n) (idk what it returns, just guessing void*), I know that the input parameter n is at the stack, and that EBP+8 is a pointer to that variable, i guess it would be like 
int* n=(int*)(uint32_t(EBP)+0x08); /*assuming EBP is a void* and sizeof(EBP)==sizeof(uint32_t)==sizeof(void*) and that the +8 math is the same in c++ uint32_t and x86 assembly..*/

I want to make a hook, that will check if n is above 7, or below 0, and if it is, then change it to 1. With ollydbg, writing the assembly code directly, i can do: 
patch the first MOV EBP,ESP instruction to JMP SHORT to the INT3 instructions behind it (I'll need 7 bytes), then change the (unused) INT3's to 
MOV EBP,ESP
JMP LONG 0068BCCD
where 0068BCCD is to the unused 0x000000000000's at the end of the file
 [image]

, then at the 0068BCCD , i can write the assembly codes to check the int pointed at by EBP+8 , and modify it if necessary:

```
PUSHAD
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8],7
JA SHORT Error
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8],0
JL SHORT Error
JMP SHORT Finished
Error:
PUSHAD
PUSH OFFSET TheString
CALL Onlink-x86.App::Output
ADD ESP,4
POPAD
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8],1
Finished:
POPAD
JMP LONG 00447493
TheString:
"Warning: label assertion failed, but (pretending its 1 and) trying to ignore.."+0x00
```

[image]

which (if i didn't mess up) is basically the equivalent of

```
void FilterIntAtEBP_8(){
int i=*(int*)(uint32_t(EBP)+8);
if(i>7 || i<0){
Output("Warning: label assertion failed, but (pretending its 1 and) trying to ignore..");
*(int*)(uint32_t(EBP)+8)=1;
}
return;
}
```

Finally, here is the question: How can i make this hook, not with Ollydbg, but with C++ ? (I saw a source code way back, a MMORPG cheat program, hooking the client, do this, but the code is lost to me )

Comment: Detouring code doesn't mean you necessarily want to cheat or break the security of an application. Sometimes you just want to add functionality to an offline program that doesn't offer plugin support.

Comment: @xmojmr the example i used, is actually Onlink, a offline "hacker simulator" game, and there is a bug in the newest version, that will crash the game when zooming in at the "world map", for whatever reason, it will call WorldMapInterfaceLabel::SetLabelPosition(-0xBAD1DEA); Problem is, this n is a switch between 0 to 7, if this function is called with any value outside, it will run to the switch default:  and crash... in this example, i fixed a crash in a game. But Assembly isn't my strong side, and i am much better at C++ . how's that for practical? ( http://ferrousmoon.com/forums/index.php )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you will want to inject a dll in the target process. To do so, you can use this code:

**Injector.h**

```
#ifndef INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Injector
{
public:
    /**
     * Loads a DLL into the remote process
     * @Return true on sucess, false on failure
    */
    bool InjectDll(DWORD processId, std::string dllPath);
private:
};

#endif // INJECTOR_H_INCLUDED
```

**Injector.cpp**

```
#include "Injector.h"

bool Injector::InjectDll(DWORD processId, std::string dllPath)
{
    HANDLE hThread, hProcess;
    void*  pLibRemote = 0;  // the address (in the remote process) where szLibPath will be copied to;

    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");
    HINSTANCE hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    char DllFullPathName[_MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(dllPath.c_str(), _MAX_PATH, DllFullPathName, NULL);

    // Get process handle
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);

    // copy file path in szLibPath
    char szLibPath[_MAX_PATH];
    strcpy_s(szLibPath, DllFullPathName);

    // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for szLibPath
    pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, NULL, sizeof(szLibPath), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );

    if (pLibRemote == NULL)
    {
        // probably because you don't have administrator's right
        return false;
    }

    // 2. Write szLibPath to the allocated memory
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pLibRemote, (void*)szLibPath, sizeof(szLibPath), NULL);

    // 3. Force remote process to load dll
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress(hKernel32,"LoadLibraryA"), pLibRemote, 0, NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Injector.h"
int main()
{
    Injector injector;
    DWORD processId = 1653; // change the process id here. 

    if (injector.InjectDll(processId, "injected.dll"))
    {
        printf("Good job, you injected the dll\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Something wrong happened\n");
    }

    while (true);
}
```

Then you have to make your dll. This is where it gets a little more complicated. First some includes:

**injected.dll**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Then we need to make a function that will detour the right location:

```
void DetourAddress(void* funcPtr, void* hook, BYTE* mem)
{
    BYTE cmd[5] = { 0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // jump place holder
    void* RVAaddr = (void*)((DWORD)funcPtr + (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL)); // base + relative address

    // make memory readable/writable
    DWORD dwProtect;
    VirtualProtect(RVAaddr, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect);

    // read memory
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)RVAaddr, &mem[2], 5, NULL);

    // write jmp in cmd
    DWORD offset = ((DWORD)hook - (DWORD)RVAaddr - 5);  // (dest address) - (source address) - (jmp size)
    memcpy(&cmd[1], &offset, 4); // write address into jmp
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)RVAaddr, cmd, 5, 0); // write jmp

    // write mem
    VirtualProtect(mem, 13, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect);

    void* returnAdress = (void*)((DWORD)RVAaddr + 5);
    memcpy(&mem[8], &returnAdress, 4); // write return address into mem

    // reprotect
    VirtualProtect(RVAaddr, 5, dwProtect, NULL);
}
```

If you need to remove your dll at some point, you will need to restore the code:

```
void PatchAddress(void* funcPtr, BYTE* mem)
{
    void* RVAaddr = (void*)((DWORD)funcPtr + (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL)); // base + relative address

    // make memory readable/writable
    DWORD dwProtect;
    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect);

    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)RVAaddr, &mem[2], 5, NULL); // write jmp

    VirtualProtect(RVAaddr, 5, dwProtect, NULL);
}
```

Next, we need to make a function out of the detoured bytes in order for the program to execute them, so that it isn't affected by our detour. Add this in global space:

```
// memory (0x5E = pop esi, 0x68 = push DWORD, 0xC3 = RETN)
BYTE detourMem[13] = { 0x5E, 0x5E, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3 };

// Convert bytes array to function
typedef void ( * pFunc)();
pFunc funcMem = (pFunc) &detourMem;

// I also added a variable as an example of what you can do with it.
DWORD var = 0;
```

After that, you need your detouring function:

```
_declspec(naked) void DetourFunction()
{
    // we need to push all flag and registers on the stack so we don't modify them by accident
    __asm
    {
        PUSHFD
        PUSHAD

        // You can do "whatever" you want here in assembly code
        // ex, put eax value into var:
        mov var, eax
    }

    printf("this code is executed everytime the detoured function is called\n");
    // Do whatever you want in c++ here
    if (var < 7)
    {
        // eax was smaller than 7
    }

    // We pop every flags and registers we first pushed so that the program continue as it was supposed to
    __asm
    {
        // we set everything back to normal
        POPAD
        POPFD
        push esi

        // we call our funcMem
        mov edx, funcMem;
        call edx
    }
}
```

Finaly, here is how your DLLMain would look like:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    DWORD detouredAddress = 0x689B; // add the RELATIVE ADDRESS of the location you want to detour
    FILE *stream;
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Only add this if you want a console to appears when you inject your dll (don't forget FreeConsole when you remove the dll)
        AllocConsole();
        freopen_s(&stream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        // If you need to know the base address of the process your injected:   
        printf("base address: 0x%X\n", (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL));

        // Our detour function
        DetourAddress((void*)detouredAddress, (void*)&DetourFunction, detourMem);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // We restore the process to have what it was before it was injected
        PatchAddress((void*)detouredAddress, detourMem);

        FreeConsole();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I understand this is a lot all at once, so if you have any questions don't hesitate!

Comment: "    DWORD detouredAddress = 0x689B; // add the RELATIVE ADDRESS of the location you want to detour"; im working with an ASLR-enabled process x.x ( i think i can still find the base address, and calculate the relative address based the base address, but ill have to do some research

Comment: How is the ASLR implemented? If it only randomize the starting address, my code will work. All you have to do is start your program, inject my dll without detouring any function, it will print the base address with "(DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL)". Attach ollydbg to your process, find the function you want to detour, and substract the address in ollydbg with the base address. The result is your relative address. Ex: In your example, the address is 0x446020, if the base address is 0xC5000, the relative address is 0x381020

Comment: You can always find your address with a signature scanner, it's very simple to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_SR5l_hquw

Comment: MyUsername112358 You need to overwrite 5 bytes of the original function, it doesn't matter about the initial setting up of the stack frame as the signatures and calling conventions are the same, but what I don't get is you're overwriting the first few bytes of the original function. 55 (push ebp) 8B EC (mov ebp, esp), so you need 2 more? Why does it not matter that you overwrite those extract 2 bytes that will be critical to the function?

Comment: It's been a while and I'm not sure I understand your question, but it appears you think I'm modifying the original function? I'm not, I'm simply detouring a call to this function to my own. For example, if in memory somewhere there is a CALL 0x00F76000 (0x00F76000 being the address of the function I'm detouring), I will instead replace it with JMP 0xAA00000 (0xAA000000 being my own function).

Comment: i guess the only reason ```GetProcAddress(hKernel32,"LoadLibraryA")``` is a valid address for both the injector and the target process is because MS Windows's ASLR implementation sucks and doesn't randomize the address of Kernel32?

Comment: fwiw one should ideally find the hKernel32 base address in the target process, which in theory may be different from your own process's kernel32 base address, that can be done with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot + Module32First - but seemingly due to a limitation in Windows' ASLR, all processes seem to share the kernel32 base address (but that's a ASLR bug that a future version of Windows may fix, ideally one shouldn't really rely on it)