# When hooking a function, why does it not matter if you overwrite the first 5 bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86, hook, machine-code

When hooking a function you need to overwrite 5 bytes of the original function, it doesn't matter about the initial setting up of the stack frame as the signatures and calling conventions are the same of the original function to your replacement function, but what I don't get is you're overwriting the first few bytes of the original function. 55 (push ebp) 8B EC (mov ebp, esp), so you need 2 more? Why does it not matter that you overwrite those extract 2 bytes that will be critical to the function?

```
00440112                         ; int __cdecl function(int, FILE *)
.text:00440112                         var_410         = byte ptr -410h
.text:00440112                         var_310         = byte ptr -310h
.text:00440112                         var_210         = byte ptr -210h
.text:00440112                         var_110         = byte ptr -110h
.text:00440112                         var_10          = byte ptr -10h
.text:00440112                         var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00440112                         arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:00440112                         arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:00440112
.text:00440112 55                                      push    ebp
.text:00440113 8B EC                                   mov     ebp, esp
.text:00440115 81 EC 10 04 00 00                       sub     esp, 410h
.text:0044011B 53                                      push    ebx
.text:0044011C 56                                      push    esi
.text:0044011D 8B 75 0C                                mov     esi, [ebp+arg_4]
.text:00440120 80 7E 04 00                             cmp     byte ptr [esi+4], 0
.text:00440124 57                                      push    edi
.text:00440125 C7 86 10 01 00 00 63 00+                mov     dword ptr [esi+110h], 63h
.text:0044012F 74 0F                                   jz      short loc_440140
.text:00440131 83 3D 7A 4E 4B 00 00                    cmp     dword_4B4E7A, 0
.text:00440138 7F 06                                   jg      short loc_440140
.text:0044013A 83 65 FC 00                             and     [ebp+var_4], 0
.text:0044013E EB 07                                   jmp     short loc_440147
```

Take the above assembly. 'E9 ?? ?? ?? ??' will replace '55 8B EC 81 EC' (?? ?? ?? ?? being the address of the function to jump to), so the way I see it is the allocation of 0x410 on the stack for the local vars will not occur when the new function called jumps back in to the original at 0x44011B; why does this not matter? I don't see what I am missing.

If you want to reproduce the functioning code that will allow you to hook a function using this method, then see MyUsername112358's answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093398/win32-how-can-i-hook-functions-in-compiled-programs-with-c)

Comment: If your hook never jumps back into the original function, everything after the 5 byte `jmp rel32` doesn't matter.  It only matters what the original instructions were if you're trying to run them *as well* as your hook.

Comment: Yeah I will need to call the original function after the hook; in the example I have linked above he also calls the original function, but he does not seem to care that he is overwriting 2 extra bytes.

Comment: I think he either knows that he's overriding the extra bytes and he takes it into account when calling the original function, or he is just lucky and nothing breaks. The 5-byte hook used to be popular since most of the routines exported by DLLs used the prologue `mov edi, edi; push ebp; mov ebp, esp` (probably because of the stdcall convention) which is exactly 5 bytes long, so you do no harm when you replace it with the jump.

Comment: @MartinDrab A 2-byte NOP like `mov edi,edi` is not standard.  Microsoft includes that in functions in DLLs specifically to make them hot-patchable.  IIRC, there's an MSVC compiler option or `declspec` attribute for it.  The rest of the stack-frame setup with `ebp` is fairly standard, but compilers (clang and gcc) default to `-fomit-frame-pointer` on i386 Linux, so even that part isn't guaranteed in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I forgot about the hotpatching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, if you intend to be able to execute the original code, you can't just cut off at the 5 byte boundary. You will have to disassemble and copy the instructions that cover the first 5 bytes as a whole.

You can check out my [`ia32hook`](https://github.com/a3f/ia32hook), which uses [OllyDbg](http://ollydbg.de)'s [disassembler](http://ollydbg.de/disasm.zip) to find out where to cut off. [The relevant snippet](https://github.com/a3f/ia32hook/blob/master/hook.c#L200):

```
#include "ollydisasm/disasm.h"

static inline unsigned long CleanBiteOff(const unsigned char *ptr, size_t amount)
{
    static t_disasm disasm;
    unsigned long size = 0;
    do {size += Disasm(ptr+size, 16, ptr+size, &disasm, DISASM_SIZE);} while(size < amount);
    return size;
}
```

The `size` returned is the number of bytes you need to copy. At the end of the trampoline where you copy over these bytes have a jump back to `(char*)func+size` and everything is well again.

The answer you linked, also didn't flush the instruction cache and would have a serious problem if the instruction pointer happened to point at the bytes you're about to patch. You should pause the threads, and assert that `eip` isn't pointing to the bytes you're about to patch.

If this isn't for learning purposes, consider using a solution like [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) instead.

Comment: You don't need the first 3 bytes as the detoured function will have the same signature and calling convention as the trampoline. Other than that thank you for your answer, it was nicely explained.

Comment: Why is the third parameter 'ip' a hardcoded address? '0x00401AAC'

Comment: @MikeO I can't recall, why I had set `ip` at that value. As you are just interested in finding out the instruction sizes, you can ignore it. If the disassembler doesn't mind a zero, you should rather put a zero in to denote that it doesn't matter.

Comment: When I am learning I try to understand everything going on, so I become a better programmer meaning here even if it does not matter for the job at hand, I would like to understand why it does not matter. 

Looking here http://ollydbg.de/Help/Disasm.htm it says ip is necessary to decode destinations of relative jumps and calls. and here http://ollydbg.de/srcdescr.htm it says srcip is the address of the command.

Comment: If part of the first five bytes is an instruction wth relative addressing, you will need `ip` in order to calculate the new address, you are going to use in the trampoline. I assumed that no relative addressing will be there. Therefore, you can ignore `ip`, as it won't affect the instruction sizes, only the value. I changed the snippet to use `ptr` instead of some random hardcoded value.