# C++ hook function of compiled library for debugging

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, 64-bit, hook

For debugging purposes in want to get arguments of some function in compiled library on each call. I know I could recompile library, but it could take half of day for some libraries(Qt for example).

Consider this function in compiled library

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    static QString getUpper(const QString &str);
};
```

Program that includes this SomeClass from library

```
void printArguments(const QString &str)
{
    qDebug() << str; //here we print argument
}

int main()
{
    //function that I need
    hookFunction((void*)&SomeClass::getUpper, (void*)&printArguments);
    SomeClass::getUpper("Hi"); // here I will see "Hi" in console
}
```

I have found some [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093398/win32-how-can-i-hook-functions-in-compiled-programs-with-c), but I don`t need dll injection. This is my program that include library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution

This [library(PolyHook)](https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook) do what I want.